# Flutter: how to return a bool value when listening to firebase snapshot?

Tags: firebase, asynchronous, flutter

I am trying to check if the Firestore document exists with this code:

```
Future<bool> checkRegisterState2() async {

  bool _isregistered;

  await userRef.snapshots().listen((datasnapshot) {
      if (datasnapshot.exists) {
        _isregistered = true;
      }else{
        _isregistered = false;
      }
    });

    if(_isregistered){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

but it seems like that the if-else statement is not waiting for the result of the firebase snapshot and therefore saying that the value of _isregistered is null.

May I ask what is the proper way to return a true value if the Firestore document exists?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but you could either use a Stream or a Future depending on your use case

```
Stream<bool> isRegistered() {
  return userRef.snapshots().map((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.exists)
}

Future<bool> isRegistered() async {
  return await userRef.get().then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.exists)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A very rudimentary way to do this would be with:

```
if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('${snapshot.error}'); // or something similar
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the reasoning about preferring `.listen()` over `.then()`? Are you awaiting the document to be created before reacting upon it or are your only interest to see whether a users exists or not?

For debugging I am particularly fond of print() statement. What does the log tell you if you add `print(datasnapshot)` before `if (datasnapshot.exists) {`

Another thing: rather than having the additional if/else{} statement why don't you simply return the value of the bool `_isRegistered`?