# Function always return false even with a valid ID

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have this code to check if a gameId exists on Firestore. Even when I provide a valid gameId, it returns false although the name of the player is actually printed to the console!

```
Future<bool> checkTwoPlayerCode(String gameId) async {
    final document = _tictactoeCollection.doc(gameId);

    await document.get().then((snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists) {
        print(snapshot.get('playerOne'));
        return true;
      }
    });
    return false;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/937429/jack)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58721808/8552587) to another post, this solves the issue I was having:

```
Future<bool> checkTwoPlayerCode(String gameId) async {
    final document = _tictactoeCollection.doc(gameId);
    return await document
        .get()
        .then((DocumentSnapshot snapshot) => snapshot.exists);
  }
```